# JS Proxy Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, proxy-pattern

I use this code to override the window.alert function.
The function replaces breaks by \r\n.
It works fine in Firefox, but ofcourse not in IE.
Im getting the error: Property or method not supported.

```
(function() {
  var proxied = window.alert;
  window.alert = function(txt) {
    txt = txt.replace(/<br>/g, "\r\n");
    return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
  };
})();
```

Please help me find the solution!
Thank you

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this, in case window.alert is not a "real" function in IE:

```
(function() {
  var proxied = window.alert;
  window.alert = function(txt) {
    txt = txt.replace(/<br>/g, "\r\n");
    return proxied(txt);
 };
})();
```

Sorry, untested, Does it work?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now the error is gone, and the alert is showing, but breaks are not replaced. It's still working fine in FF though. Any ideas?

Comment: I changed the location of the code in my script and it's working fine now in both IE and FF. Thank you Victor! 

@Tim, I appriciate your input, and I know it's not the best way to do it, but otherwise I had to replace the alert function in my scripts to a custom made alert function. Knowing there are over 1000 scripts on my website, that's just not doable.

Answer (score 0):

This would be fine for native JavaScript functions but is highly dangerous with methods of host objects such as `window`. Host objects are not subject to the normal rules of native JavaScript objects, and can (and do) behave largely as they please, often differently in different browsers. Therefore I strongly recommend not pursuing this idea for `window.alert` or any other host methods.