# This works in Chrome but not IE, why?

Tags: javascript, global, apply, window-object

```
var shell = function (method) {
        window[method].apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    };

shell('alert', 'monkey!');
```

Comment: because IE is evil

Comment: See the answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120804/difference-between-array-slice-and-array-slice

Comment: no, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1) is ok.

Comment: @Tim he's already using `Array.prototype.slice`

Comment: @Jimmy this is not the case here. The standard doesn't insist this behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**alert.apply** is the problem. **Alert is not part of the language**, so it may not be even a function. It is **implementation-dependent**.

Comment: Right - IE exposes APIs on `window` and on DOM elements to Javascript, but the exposure is limited and you generally cannot treat such things as if they were "real" Javascript components.

Comment: Good point, but then shouldn't this work:

    var shell = function (method) {
            var fn = window[method];

            fn.apply = Function.prototype.apply;
            fn.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        };

    shell('alert', 'monkey!');

Comment: No. The problem is with the fact that `window` is a host object and `alert` is a property of a host object, and host objects are not obliged to behave like native objects. The following question is similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060318/js-proxy-pattern-problem

Comment: Stupid IE. I gave up and used eval if the better way fails.